# The rowcolor command for table is changing colors of the matrix rows as well

Tags: tables, beamer, color, matrices

I am preparing a beamer presentation where I want to use colored rows in a table, for which I am using `\rowcolors{2}{green!20}{blue!20}` in the preamble of latex code.

The command works fine for table however, somehow it affects the pmatrix as well (shown below). Is there any way to avoid it? I want the matrix with plain background.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\rowcolors{2}{green!20}{blue!20}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} Column 1  & Column 2 \\
\hline
23      & 234 \\
234     & 56  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

$$\lambda= \left( \begin{matrix}
        \lambda_1   & 0         &\hdots   & 0  \\
            0       & \lambda_2 &\hdots   & 0    \\
            0       &   0       & \ddots  & 0 \\
            0       &   0       &  \hdots &\lambda_n
        \end{matrix}      \right) $$.       
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit 1: After the @Warner's suggestion I tried defining `\rowcolors` command within the Table environment and it works. It no longer affects the matrix.

Warner's approach requires me to add some extra lines, each time I include a new table. I am preparing a set of lectures where I would like to have a global setting (if possible). It will reduce code length as well as make it consistent throughout.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

Comment: Well, `array`s and `tabular`s are inherently similar, so the fact that `\rowcolors` spills over makes sense. If you want a localised change, you may have to consider adding `\rowcolors` only where you want it, or to issue `\rowcolors` (with a local scope/within a group) with appropriate row colours that differ from the global scope colours.

Comment: Does your presentation contain other tables as well? If so, do you want `\rowcolors` to also apply to them?

Comment: @Warner advice helped. I still look for a global setting/solution, so appended this requirement in the question.

Comment: @leandriis yes It is actually a set of lectures containing many tables and I would like to have a consistent appearance for all tables.

Comment: If your document contains significantly less matrices than tables, it may be easier to keep the global setting and locally reset the color for the individual matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrInner{row{odd}={blue9},row{even}={green9},row{1}={yellow9}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tblr}{cc}
\hline
  Column 1  & Column 2 \\
\hline
  23      & 234 \\
  234     & 56  \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

$$\lambda= \left( \begin{matrix}
        \lambda_1   & 0         &\hdots   & 0  \\
            0       & \lambda_2 &\hdots   & 0    \\
            0       &   0       & \ddots  & 0 \\
            0       &   0       &  \hdots &\lambda_n
        \end{matrix}      \right) $$.
      
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I saw your post and had exactly the same problem, just solved it for my file. I highly recommend you to create a new table environment where you can configure ONLY such table.

(Because of [H] , \usepackage{float} is required)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{float}

%------------Custom table--------------------------------------
\newenvironment{MyTabular}[1]{% #1 = column types
    \setlength{\intextsep}{3pt} %Space between text and table
    \rowcolors{2}{green!20}{blue!20} %Color config
    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \begin{tabular}{#1} \rowcolor{yellow} %First row color
}{%
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}
%--------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
\begin{MyTabular}{cc}
\hline
Column 1  & Column 2 \\
\hline
23      & 234 \\
234     & 56  \\
\hline
\end{MyTabular}

$$\lambda= \left( \begin{matrix}
        \lambda_1   & 0         &\hdots   & 0  \\
            0       & \lambda_2 &\hdots   & 0    \\
            0       &   0       & \ddots  & 0 \\
            0       &   0       &  \hdots &\lambda_n
        \end{matrix}      \right) $$.       
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the global answer we were looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following;

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{etoolbox}        % <---
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{% <---
    \rowcolors{2}{green!20}{blue!20}
                            }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Coloring only \texttt{tabular}s}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} Column 1  & Column 2 \\
\hline
23      & 234 \\
234     & 56  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\[
\lambda= \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1   & 0         &\hdots   & 0  \\
            0       & \lambda_2 &\hdots   & 0    \\
            0       &   0       & \ddots  & 0 \\
            0       &   0       &  \hdots &\lambda_n
        \end{pmatrix}
\].
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you gave other tables' environments, you can add coloring definitions also for them.

[image]